# Csv File Not Found in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, import

I am probably missing something obvious but my python code does not recognise my csv file although it is included in my package. As a result, I am getting a FileNotFoundException. Here is my error:

```
 from multiplication import views
 File "/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/multiplication/views.py", 
 line 15, in <module>
 with open('data.csv','r') as csv_file:
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'
```

Here is a picture of my setup, including the file in the package: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1pW7.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start a Django by `python manage.py runserver`, the current working path is where your manage.py locates. If you put your `data.csv` under the same folder, it would work. Alternatively, provide the absolute path to your data file：

```
DATA_SRC = '/Users/NikolasPapastavrou/firstProject/multiplication/data.csv'

with open(DATA_SRC, 'r') as csv_file:
    // do your work...
```

Comment: @nikpap Glad it helps